# How do I use source code methods in my pybuilder script?

Tags: python, pybuilder

I started a pybuilder project and I'm trying to get access to my methods defined in:

```
../projName/src/main/python/overUnder.py
```

in a script I've written:

```
../projName/src/main/scripts/overUnder-runner.py
```

The source code of `overUnder.py` has a method like

```
def itsOver(N):
    ...
```

and I want to call it in `overUnder-runner.py`, but all I can come up with so far is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

from projName import overUnder

itsOver(9000)
```

I run

```
pyb publish
```

then

```
pip install target/dist/projName-1.0.dev0/dist/projName-1.0.dev0.tar.gz
```

then I try to run the script with

```
overUnder-runner.py
```

but I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jbiebs/projName/venv/bin/overUnder-runner", line 4, in <module>
    from projName import overUnder
ImportError: No module named projName
```

I have

```
name = "projName"
```

in my `build.py` file. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! I've figured it out. In `overUnder-runner.py`, I don't want

```
from projName import overUnder
```

but rather

```
from overUnder import itsOver
```

It's not

```
from <package> import <filename>
```

but

```
from <filename> import <method>
```